# Iterate all pages and crawler table's elements save as dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I need to loop all the entries of all the **pages** from this [link](http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=425000), then click the menu `check` in the red part (please see the image below) to enter the detail of each entry:

[image]

The objective is to cralwer the infos from the pages such as image below, and save left part as column names and right part as rows:

[image]

The code I used:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=425000'
content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridview'})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df.head(5))
```

Out:

```
   序号               工程名称  ...        发证日期 详细信息
0 NaN  假日万恒社区卫生服务站装饰装修工程  ...  2020-07-07   查看
```

The code for entering the detailed pages:

```
url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=308891&t=toDetail&GCBM=202006202001'

content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"detailview"}).findAll("tr")
 
for elements in table:
    inner_elements = elements.findAll("td", attrs={"class":"label"})
    for text_for_elements in inner_elements:
        print(text_for_elements.text)
```

Out:

```
        工程名称：
        施工许可证号：
        所在区县：
        建设单位：
        工程规模(平方米)：
        发证日期：
        建设地址：
        施工单位：
        监理单位：
        设计单位：
        行政相对人代码：
        法定代表人姓名：
        许可机关：
```

As you can see, I only get column name, no entries have been successfully extracted.

In order to loop all pages, I think we need to use post requests, but I don't know how to get headers.

Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will go for all pages and gets the data into a DataFrame and saves them to `data.csv`.

(**!!! Warning !!!** there are 2405 pages total, so it takes a long time to get them all):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn/eportal/ui?pageId=425000'
payload = {'currentPage': 1, 'pageSize':15}

def scrape_page(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    return {td.get_text(strip=True).replace('：', ''): td.find_next('td').get_text(strip=True) for td in soup.select('td.label')}


all_data = []
current_page = 1

while True:
    print('Page {}...'.format(current_page))
    payload['currentPage'] = current_page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=payload).content, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.select('a:contains("查看")'):
        u = 'http://bjjs.zjw.beijing.gov.cn' + a['href']
        d = scrape_page(u)
        all_data.append(d)
        pprint(d)

    page_next = soup.select_one('a:contains("下一页")[onclick]')
    if not page_next:
        break

    current_page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints the data to screen and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Sorry, one more question, if we want to crawler only top 100 pages contents, how to change your code?

Comment: @ahbon inside de `while` loop check `current_page` if it's greater than 100 and if it's then do `break`.